# C# Silverlight - XmlDictionary from Uri

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, filestream, relative-path

I've been developing a Silverlight application for a company's website and have encountered a problem.

Up until now I have been programming this locally, now I need to publish the program onto the website; the issue is that FileStream can only access local files with elevated permissions.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"E:\Users\LUPUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Lycaon5\Lycaon5\acids.xdb", FileMode.Open))
 {
using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fileStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
  {
    //Read the XML file out.
  }
 }
```

Without changing anything to do with XmlDictionaryReader reader - How could I go about reading the files from a relative Uri?

Many Thanks,

Rob.

P.s. Apologies for the lack of formatting, me cave man, me don't know how.

Comment: for the next time: [how to format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

Embed the file with your assembly when you compile.  Then you can read it as a resource stream: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28VS.95%29.aspx

(Make sure you embed your file as type `Resource` for this method to work)

Your code *might* look something like this to get the file stream:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/MyAssemblyName;component/acids.xdb", UriKind.Relative);
StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
Stream fileStream = streamInfo.Stream;

using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fileStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
{
    //Read the XML file out.
}
```

EDIT: As Tim S pointed out, this is only good for if the data file is static and fixed at compile time.  Otherwise you can use other methods to download the file from a website (as he linked to).

Comment: If the XmlDictionary is very static, this is good.  If it should be more easily updatable, you can read it from a URL, maybe using WebClient like http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/reading-files-asynchronously-using-webclient-class-in-silverlight/

Comment: That `new StreamResourceInfo(uri)` constructor doesn't exist. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602802(v=vs.95). Did you mean `Application.GetResourceStream(uri)`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=vs.95)

Comment: @TimS. Yeah, I did.  That's what I get for editing parts of code with copy/pasting.  I always miss-copy something. >< Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the file from which I am grabbing the data is very dynamic and will probably be altered every other day automatically; I've tried using Tim's approach before but to no avail - XmlDictionaryReader doesn't like it. I'll try again and then vote accordingly :) 

Thanks